# Checking parameter classes in PHP

Tags: php, html, drupal

At the moment, I have the following:

```
<?php if ($custom != ""): ?> 
    <div class="head-row5" id="custom">
        <?php print $custom?>                    
    </div><?php //head-row5 ?>                  
<?php endif; ?>
```

What is returned is something like....

```
<div class="block block-block" id="block-block-15">
    <div class="title">
        <h3></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content"><p style="text-align: center;"><a href="website linkage" id="T2roll"><span class="alt">Name of the linked page</span></a></p>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is find a way to print this out ONLY if the `<span class="alt">` is true.

**How would I go about doing this?**

I believe that I'm going to have to check the elements by class of this *$custom* parameter. However, I have no idea how to go about doing this.

Comment: The way that I was going about solving this was in the initial statement. I want to be able to say something along the lines of:

if(($custom != "") && (!property_exists($custom, 't2roll')) THEN include it.

Comment: I can't see a connection between your two code examples. Is the second code block the value of `$custom` or what? Do you want to check of `<span class="alt">` is included in `$custom`? In your second block your are also missing a closing div of the `class=content`-div.

Comment: @lorem Yes, the way that it works is that `$custom` is goes through four different places and appends that `<div class="head-row5" id="custom"></div>` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['block_id'] === 'target_block_id') {
    // do something for this block

  }
}
```